# Raspberry pi 4 Low voltage warning

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

Hi I have a Raspberry pi 4 which is used to drive a car for a project. Pi is powered using a hat connected through gpio ports. I am using 2 x 18650mah 3.7v for powering the car and rpi. Most of the time it shows Low voltage warning and the status lights starts to dim. Is there any way to power rpi without using the 5v pin in gpio and connecting an external power supply using Usb Power Bank. Also I found out that i accidently powered the rpi from both the gpio and the usb.

Comment: Unfortunately, some of these power hats don't actually deliver enough power, particularly with changing loads and additional hardware connected (such as a display). Try getting a better power hat.

Comment: `5v pin in gpio` ... the 5 V pin is not part of the GPIO ... only some of the pins in the header are used for GPIO

Comment: Your question is devoid of information needed to give you any sort of a reasonable answer. Batteries in parallel or series?, how you regulate to get 5V? - you don't even get the battery rating correct: `18650mah`??? [Read this](https://commonsensehome.com/18650-battery/) re your battery, [do some math](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/118825/powering-raspberry-pi-4-on-the-move-using-power-bank/118831#118831) & edit your question. I suspect you'll have a [very short drive](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/135942/83790) in your car.

Comment: The Pi4 is a poor choice for a battery powered device - it is the most power hungry model and almost certainly the processing power is not needed.

Comment: @jsotola I am sorry i am new to rpi. When i googled i found out that rpi is having Raspberry Pi 4 GPIO Pinout has 40 pins: 26 GPIO pins, two 5V pins, two 3V3 pins, and 7 ground pins (0V). 2x5v pins and 2x3v pins so  my hat is using these pins to power raspberry pi. I am not using any power source other than the batteries.

Comment: @Seamus I am using 2* 18650 button top 2220mah batteries my bad for providing wrong information. I have provided that i am using a hat to power up my rpi. The batteries are in series.

Answer (score 2):

The Pi requires 5V +/- 0.25 volts to operate properly.  You will get the low voltage warning if the Pi has less than 4.65 volts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a capacitor between GND and 5V close to the 5V pin? Maybe the voltage is not stable and drops on load changes.

If you want to power the Pi and the HAT seperately, the easiest way would be to just cut-off the 5V and 3.3V pins (but NOT the GND pins) on the pin header of the raspberry pi. This should work, but I have never done this myself.